# HTML tab icons not showing on website when live

Tags: html, tabs, favicon

I have a website that is live at the moment and have added the required code to my HTML files to display the icon on different tabs

I have tried

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And

```html
<link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon.ico"/>
```

I've also tried adding the icon file to the directory that my HTML is hosted on and even changed the sizes and used different image types such an .PNG instead, but still no luck.

I'm using NameCheap to host my website and it's managed through cPanel.

Whenever I view the HTML through localhost it shows the icons on the tabs.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be the issue and how I can get my tab icons to display on my website? I'm stumped...

Could it be to do with who I'm hosting my site with?

Thanks

Comment: Can you let us know the website? May be it could be due to caching issue in your browser. Try using incognito mode.

Comment: Yes it's www.shannonleahwatson.co.uk I have already tried clearing my cache and I just tried using incognito but it's still showing the default icon of a blank page

Comment: Is the cache bro, you must do CTRL+F5 in page

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño I have tried this, still shows the default icon

Comment: it's a wordpress ?

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño no I coded the website from scratch for a university project

Comment: Idk about scratch but you can access in the HTML code directly ? , see if some file has the line with .ico or something like that with "AgentRansack" and then remove it and make for sure you are setting this icon in the correct site

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño What I meant by scratch was that I coded the HTML files myself, and I have checked for the .ICO file in the HTML and the only mentions of it are in the header where they're supposed to be

Comment: cache from server.., did you upload this changes by ftp ?

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño I did, yes.. So that is most likely the potential issue

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Namecheap support and they were helpful but still didn't fix my issue there and then, but I did notice overnight the image had updated and my tab icons were live so I'm assuming it was a server cache issue and I just needed to be patient, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right code.

The problem is between the cache or the propagation of the icon (this is more rare but can occur sometime).

You can try to reach your website with different browsers in the incognito mode.

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried looking on IE and Edge but it still didn't give me an icon, only the default icons for both browsers (IE logo for Internet Explorer)

Comment: Same for me. 
Your problem is not with css or html.
Like I said, it can be the propagation, I don't have the exact name of this phenomenon but it have occured to me sometimes.
I wish there's no need to wait hours.